# Store 'null' string in .env file Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I need to store 'null' as a string in the .env file.

Now I have `VAR_NAME=null` in the file and if I try to read the value with
`env('VAR_NAME')` it doesn´t return nothing.

Is there any way way to store the value as a string?

Comment: `VAR_NAME=` doesn't work?

Comment: I think it works as expected. The value is null, then env('VAR_NAME') returns an empty value. What I need is that env('VAR_NAME') returns a 'null' string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anser to my question seems to be, no, you can't.

The solution was to use the second parameter of `env('VAR_NAME','default')`.

The problem is that `env()` doesn't return the default value because `VAR_NAME` exists and have a value.

I comented `VAR_NAME` in the env file just in case I need to use it later.

Comment: As a workaround, to use `'null'` as a queue driver, I modified my config file to have `'driver' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync') ?: 'null'`. This falls back to `'null'` if the env value is falsey

Answer (score 4):

You can store a blank string in your `.env` file by leaving the space after `=` blank, such as `

```
VAR_NAME=
```

But it won't return null, it will return an empty string:

```
var_dump(env("VAR_NAME");
//string(0) ""
```

If you want it to return `NULL`, then use

```
VAR_NAME=NULL
```

Now, if you want the string `"NULL"`, you would have to have some custom logic to convert it at runtime, for example:

```
$test = env("VAR_NAME") ? env("VAR_NAME"):"NULL";
var_dump($test);
// string(4) "NULL"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `VAR_NAME=null`  in `.env` file and try to print it as `{{ env('VAR_NAME') }}`  it wouldn't show anything. But the value is still null.

You can see it by using `{{ var_dump(env('VAR_NAME'))}}`

But if you want to return `null` as a string, I don't think it's possible. You would probably need to specify any other string and consider it as `null`.

If you just wanted to store it in a global variable, you can save it in the `config/app.php` file and use it as `{{Config::get('app.var_name')}}` This would return `null`.

```
 //config/app.php
'var_name' => 'null',
```

Now access it via:

```
config('app.var_name')
```

or

```
Config::get('app.var_name')
```

Comment: But how can I recover the value as a 'null' string?

Comment: This works but is not what I want. I 'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's getenv function and pass a default value. So if the value is not existing then it will return the default value for eg:

```
getenv('VAR_NAME',null)
```

This will return the value if VAR_NAME is existing in the .env file else it will return you the default value which is null

Comment: getenv() gave me an error but this response gave me a clue of how to solve, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

L8 try

```php
env('VAR_NAME') ?: "null";
```

Cover cases:

- if `VAR_NAME` not exists in .env you will get 'null'
- if `VAR_NAME=` in .env you will get 'null'